# Unable to Unserilize the values in phtml Magento2

Tags: magento2, banner-slider, unserialize, promotional-banner

I have added a blockfunction in (vendor\module\Block\Dealz) as

```
public function __construct
(
 Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface $serializer
) {
$this->serializer = $serializer;
}

public function unSerialize($link)
{ 
return  $this->serializer->unserialize($link);
}
```

After that called the function in banner.phtml as

```
$blockData = $block->getBlockData();


<?php foreach ($blockData as $data):
    $banner = $data->getBannerSerialized();
     $bannerUnserialize = $block->unSerialize($banner);
?>
```

The following is the parent phtml file that i used

```
 <?php if ($type=='SliderBlock'): ?>
            <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock(vendor\module\Block\Dealz::class)
                ->setTemplate("vendor_module::slider.phtml")
                ->setData('design_id',$item->getId())
                ->toHtml() ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
       
     <?php if ($type=='BannerBlock'): ?>
         <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock(vendor\module\Block\Dealz::class)
         ->setTemplate("vendor_module::banner.phtml")
         ->setData('design_id',$item->getId())
         ->toHtml() ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

I have already used the
'$block->unSerialize()' in **slider.phtml** it gots correctly. but again try to use this in **banner.phtml** at that time i got error  as  **Unable to unserialize value**. how to fix this.

Comment: First confirm your block is called by this line : $block->unSerialize($banner);

Comment: Yes I have called as 
<?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock(vendor\module\Block\dealz::class)
         ->setTemplate("vendor_module::banner.phtml")
         ->setData('design_id',$item->getId())
         ->toHtml() ?>
In my parent phtml file

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the code of the banner.phtml file where you are calling this function  unserialize() in that phtml file , this way we can check what data you are sending to the serializer class , and if possible please do check the values before serializing in this website https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer, in this way also we can confirm if this is a valid JSON or not , If it is not a valid JSON then this type of error will come from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Need to check for the condition as

```
 if (!empty($banner)):
    $bannerUnserialize = $block->unSerialize($banner);
?>
```